# How to handle an old cross post?

Tags: discussion, flags, cross-posting

I just found [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199981/tab-completion-and-mc-problems) and realized that the OP asked the same exact question 9 minutes earlier [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47554/tab-completon-and-mc-problems). Then some days later he answered both of his questions and accepted them.

The question title/body and the answers are perfectly identical. Clearly it was a copy and paste. Both questions/answers are upvoted and there are other answers too. What should I do with them? Flag it? Which one? Or should I just leave them alone?

Comment: Well, it might be a rare case when the question fits both sites. Not sure it justifies cross posting, but don't think it's something horrible. So as for "how to handle" I personally don't think we should do anything. (downvote/flag/close etc)

Comment: unless you're a moderator, things are really easy - the very [tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) for [meta-tag:cross-posting] has pretty clear instructions for regular users: **"If you spot a user cross-posting, please make use of Moderator Flags to inform the Moderators..."** It is going to be a headache for moderator to decide what to do about the question you flagged